# Watch Ace Editor Fold

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

For a few days now I've been searching for a solution to watch the ace editor fold, so I can put the code to do something when the folding event happen. A callback would work perfectly, but there is none, as long as I know, for the folding.

I searched on this directory of the project, but I didn't find a possible answer for that:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/lib/ace/edit_session

Does anybody knows if there is a core solution for that, or I will have to develop that for my own?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

there is a changeFold event on editor.session see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.5/lib/ace/edit_session/folding.js#L343 https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/search?q=changeFold&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93